# Event willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation isn't calling

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, rotation

I have several `UIViewController`s on the application. But only on one of them `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` event is calling.

How to make `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` work for all visible views?

Comment: Did you put the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation on every UIViewController?

Comment: No, I'll try it now...

Comment: Should we add `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `shouldAutorotate` also?

Comment: These methods don't help (even they are calling).

Comment: ChrisF, you made a bad thing. This question has really cool answer but you marked it as duplicate and deleted the same answer on "original" question. So I think, nobody will find this answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RootViewController`:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = @{
        @"toInterfaceOrientation":@(toInterfaceOrientation),
        @"duration":@(duration)};
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
}
```

Other `UIViewControllers`:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:) name:@"willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation" object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(NSNotification *)notification {
    UIInterfaceOrientation toOrientation = (UIInterfaceOrientation)[notification.userInfo[@"toOrientation"] intValue];
    NSTimeInterval duration = (UIInterfaceOrientation)[notification.userInfo[@"duration"] floatValue];
    [self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toOrientation duration:duration];
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    // ...
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}
```