# How to send a notification with parameters on Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

I need to send the notification `@"willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation"` with the parameters `toInterfaceOrientation` and `duration` (**question #1**) to all `UIViewController` on the application (**question #2**). How to write code for that?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
  addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation:duration)
         name:@"willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation"
       object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
  postNotificationName:@"willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation"
                object:self];
```

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957077/event-willanimaterotationtointerfaceorientation-isnt-calling

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `postNotificationName:object:userInfo:` and bundle any parameter you wish to pass inside the `userInfo` dictionary.

Example:

You can post a notification like this

```
NSDictionary * userInfo = @{ @"toOrientation" : @(toOrientation) };
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
```

And then retrieve the information you passed, by doing:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(NSNotification *)n {
    UIInterfaceOrientation toOrientation = (UIInterfaceOrientation)[n.userInfo[@"toOrientation"] intValue];
  //..
}
```

To summarize what seen above, the selector used to handle a notification takes one optional parameter of type `NSNotification` and you can store any information you'd like to pass around inside the `userInfo` dictionary.

Comment: Code has the following errors: 1. Unexpected '@' in program. 2. Collection element of type 'UIInterfaceOrientation' (aka 'enum UIInterfaceOrientation') is not an Objective-C object.

Comment: You need to wrap `toOrientation` between parenthesis. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work the way you think it does. A notification message call has one optional parameter, which is an `NSNotification` object:

```
-(void)myNotificationSelector:(NSNotification*)note;
-(void)myNotificationSelector;
```

The notification object has a property, `userInfo`, which is a dictionary that can be used to pass relevant information.  But you can't register arbitrary selectors to be called by the notification center.  You pass that dictionary with the notification by using `-postNotificationName:object:userInfo:` instead of `-postNotificationName:object:`; the `userInfo` parameter is just an `NSDictionary` that you create.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to send a notification to all (or all visible) `UIViewController`s of the application?

Comment: Only if they've all registered for that notification.  Note that there is an existing notification, `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` that is available if you ask for it by calling `[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]` (but you still must register each view controller for it).

Comment: `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` is calling after a rotation - not inside the rotation as `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`. Sorry for possible noob question, but we are calling `postNotificationName` with `object:self` parameter - will it be sent only to `self` object?

Comment: It will be sent to all objects that passed that pointer to the `object` parameter when they called `NSNotificationCenter -addObserver:selector:name:object:`.

Comment: May I use `object:nil` on `addObserver:selector:name:object:` and on `postNotificationName:object:` both to send the notification to all subscribers?

Comment: Absolutely.  In fact, you only have to pass `nil` in `addObserver:::`; you'll then get all the notifications, even if `postNotificationName:object:` has a non-`nil` value for `object`.

Comment: Thank you a lot! May you also help to pass `UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation` and `NSTimeInterval duration` parameters with the notification?

Comment: See Gabriele's code.  You need to push both values into `NSNumber`s, because `NSDictionary` can only hold object values.

Answer (score 0):

You make an easier to call method, which takes less arguments and does the complex call for you.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
  addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(doStuff)
         name:@"willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation"
       object:nil];

- (void)doStuff {
  [self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:someOrientation
                                    toOrientation:someOtherOrientation
                                         duration:1];
}
```

---

You shouldn't be calling `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:` yourself though.  Instead make a method that's called form that method that contains the code you want to activate on rotation and also other times.

Comment: But how to pass the parameters using `userInfo`?